# search results to show individual ACF fields from inside custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types, search, advanced-custom-fields

In need of some help. I have my search results showing the custom post type with all the ACF fields inside. What I want is the search result to show the ACF singularly with a field name of file_name that is a text field and file field file_pdf. together they would be one result from any given amount of posts from the user. I can't seem to understand the way to code this. I'm currently using relevanssi plugin. 
I'm struggling with the idea of filtering just those two fields to show in the results.

```
function wpb_search_filter($query)
{
    global $current_user;
    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin())
        $query->set('author', $current_user->ID);
    // $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'pricing', 'attachment' ) );
    $query->set('meta_query', array(
        'key'       => 'file_pdf',
        'value'     => $query->query['s']
    ));
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'wpb_search_filter');
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just change the template for this custom post type in search results?

Comment: At the moment the search only brings up the post as a whole with all fields in one. I wondered if there must be more to my function then just just that.

Comment: Yes, you can use a template for search results to change the content displayed.

Comment: I had a mad 30mins there. I was going around in circles not thinking clearly. All is sorted now